# Is there a way to do multiple screenshots using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a code to check out whether that instagram account exist or not

```
exist=[]
url = []

for i in cli:
  r = requests.get("https://www.instagram.com/"+i+"/")
  if r.apparent_encoding == 'Windows-1252':
    exist.append(i)
    url.append("instagram.com/"+i+"/")

exist
['duolingoenglishtest',
'duolingo',
'duolingoespanol',
'duolingofrance']
```

I want to do a screenshot for each instagram account, and I think have found a way to screenshot each instagram account, but I don't know how to change the screenshots name for each image.

```
for ss in exist:
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/"+ss+"/")
    time.sleep(5)
    screenshot = driver.save_screenshot('Pictures/Insta2.png')
    driver.quit()
```

I really appreciate the help,
Thanks!

Comment: Why are you quitting the driver in the for-loop?

Comment: when I do a screenshot, i want the the driver to exit after 5 seconds, is there something something wrong with that? i would really appreciate the explanation since I'm still learning Python! @MatthiasL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your exist entries as filenames:

```
screenshot = driver.save_screenshot('Pictures/' + ss + '.png')
```

Or setup a numbering scheme:

```
    i = 1
    for ss in exist:
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/"+ss+"/")
        time.sleep(5)
        screenshot = driver.save_screenshot('Pictures/Insta' + str(i) + '.png')
        i += 1
        driver.quit()
```

Comment: I tried to do the numbering scheme but ended up with this 
`ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused` 
and this 
`MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=55925): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/6f8d41669701d300faeb209eb0ecd90d/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f8c483b1f40>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))`

Comment: I have fixed it btw, and I used the numbering scheme and it works! i have accepted your anwer thx!